# Can you embed a main clause, or does it always have to be subordinate?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, phrase-usage, subordinate-clauses

Like in the following example:

Some of you may not have heard of Dr Watkins, but he is an expert in psychology from the University of Oxford, and he said that “...”

Or should the comma before ‘and he said that’ be removed?

The commas are placed here primarily to mimic pauses in spoken English.

Thank you!

Comment: "Subordinate" **means** "embedded". And vice versa. N.B. This applies to indirect quotations; direct quotations live in their own grammatical universe, as reported speech.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of *main clause* is simple enough.

> "A clause that can form a complete sentence standing alone, having a subject and a predicate." [Oxford languages]

> "Main clauses make sense on their own. 'I like bananas. ' is a simple sentence which is made up of a main clause." *threschoolrun.com*.

There is a distinction between **grammatical** dependence and **logical** dependence.

Your example can be written as three **grammatically** independent sentences, joined by conjunctions in the form "A, but B and C".  Each of the three can stand alone with its own independent truth conditions.  You could write:

> Some of you may not have heard of Dr Watkins.  He is an expert in psychology from the University of Oxford.  He said that “...”.

The use of *but* sets up a kind of logical relationship.

> Although some of you may not have heard of Dr. Watkins , he is and expert....

All that (or something like it) can be done by that one short conjunction *but*.  In the above version, I have **grammatically** subordinated sentence A to sentence B, which functions as the **grammatical** main clause.  Arguably it, along with sentence C, is also the logically most important ('main' in the sense of 'most important' clause.

However, as quoted, your sentence consists of three clauses of equal standing.

Comment: The point about logical versus grammatical subordination is interesting - I would argue that the logical subordination comes about as a result of ordering the material, with the most important term or proposition coming at the end of the compound sentence. It could be articulated in different ways, each having a slightly different nuance in terms of logical subordination.

Answer (score 1):

Your example features 'FANBOYS' (or coordinating) conjunctions (for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so) and is thus a compound sentence, not a complex one.

Compound sentences join sentences of equal standing.

Complex sentences feature subordinating conjunctions (e.g. although, since, because, etc) and these are the ones that feature a main clause and subordinating clause.